# How to get url from django to javascript with pk

Tags: javascript, django

> I'm having trouble to get the url from django to JavaScript. How can I get the url with pk? the error that I receive Not found: "post/(?Pslug:pk\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}\b(-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\b){3}-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}\b)/$'

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import reverse
from . import views
import twitter.views

urlpatterns = [
    path("chatbot/(?P<str:pk>\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}\b(-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\b){3}-\b[0-9A-Fa-f] {12}\b)/$'/", views.chatbot, name='chatbot_chatbot'),
    path("post/(?P<slug:pk>\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}\b(-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\b){3}-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}\b)/$'", views.chatbot_process, name='post'),
    path("", views.landing, name='home')
```

]

**Javascript**

```
$.get("/post/(?P<slug:pk>\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}\b(-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}\b){3}-\b[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}\b)/$')", {input_text: rawText, user_text: new_value}).done(function (data) {
    const msgText = data;
    appendMessage(BOT_NAME, BOT_IMG, "left", msgText);
  });
```

Comment: Is the `pk` you're trying to match a UUID instead of a slug? When you call the URL in your JS you need to use the formatted string with the pk, why are you passing that "regex"?

Comment: You are mixing path syntax and url syntax.

Comment: You're not going to see `?P<slug:pk>` from JS in the browser, so that will never match. 

Is this JS part of a Django template, or a separate JS file? If it's in a template you can put a `reverse` in when you want it so it's correct when it renders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get your params in your javascript

```
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
let pk = url.searchParams.get("pk") // Get value of parameter pk
```